# Visual WebPart does not recognize tag for resources

Tags: visual-web-part, resources

I created a visual webpart from VS2012. The headers of the `ascx` page are

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyVisualWebPart.ascx.cs" Inherits="MySPSolution.WebParts.MyVisualWebPart.MyVisualWebPart" %>
```

later in the code i have

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:MyResources,Title%>" />
```

The problem is that when i use the `<%$` there is a build error says

*The name 'InitializeControl' does not exist in the current context*

It's not that it doesn't find a key in `MyResources`. It doesn't compile at all. By the way `MyResources` is in `App_GlobalResources` folder, and the same usage works in an `aspx` page.

What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Is the .designer.cs / g.cs file still generated correctly? Your issue seems similar to a behavior caused by a bug that trigger an "empty" designer file. Try to confirm that all the visual web part files have the expected content.

Comment: You are right `g.cs` file is empty. Can i fix it?

Comment: Gotcha! Please - see if your issue is the same described in [this answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/57305/5173). If that's the case, you can upvote that answer.

Comment: Also, even if the solution in the above link does not work for your case, the empty g.cs file is probably the cause. We "just" need to understand *why* it is empty. Any sign of error in the .ascx file? Red underline, warning or such?

Comment: no i don't think that it is the length of the contents. After the 8 lines of header i have an empty line and then a line with the <asp:Label ... /> tag

Comment: No, no other error. I haven't write any code even in ascx.cs file. Just the label tag with the $Resources. If i replace `<%$Resources:MyResources,Title%>` with `Title` the g.cs file is generated correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I have found it.

As of today 8 april 2013 this seems to be a bug with the current version of Visual Studio 2013 and SharePoint 2013 developer tools.

This link points to the original Connect discussion: [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/776185/localization-of-a-sharepoint-visual-web-part-the-name-initializecontrol-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context). All context match: attempt to use a resource in the .ascx file, empty g.cs file, error message...

> Hello, I am running VS Ultimate 2012 11.0.51106.01 Update 1 with the SharePoint Developer Tools Preview 2. I've been trying to build a localized SharePoint Visual Web Part but I am getting the infamous 'The name 'InitializeControl' does not exist in the current context' error when trying to reference a project resource file in the user control's ASCX source. The ascx.g.cs file subsequently becomes blank and the project no longer compiles. How can resource files be used inside an ASCX control with the new 2012 Visual Web Part? Thanks in advance for your help, Raphael.

As you can see the reporting user seems to have the same error. See the discussion in the original connect link and also [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/af139e08-4d64-4685-b1d8-b3e03a9b748d). Seems that the current workaround is to set the resource via code behind. Part of a grand plan to have only one resource system (instead of the 14 resource + app_globalresources) it seems, but until they complete the plan we will have to live with it.

Comment: i am trying to update to `VS2012 Update 2, Tools RTM` as 
'Vincent BIRET' suggested in the second link you provided. I'll let you know

Comment: The update didn't fix the problem. I will try code behind now

Comment: @pbaris ok. If you are in an urge to fix that, also consider localizing the label via code behind. It isn't optimal IMHO, but from what we have gathered so far, it would seem that your error IS caused by the resource usage in the ascx file... so not many choices there.

Comment: Yes code behind worked. Not the best solution but till the fix...

Comment: Look - If the error is given by the <%$Resources usage, removing it is *bound to* fix the problem. Now, ensuring that the issue is caused by the above bug would be harder. Still, all evidences point to a common problem... so I assume you have no choice. Glad you sorted it for now.

Comment: @pbaris - Could you add to the original question a notice about the version ids of both Visual studio and the dev tools you where using? Since I feel this question is targeted to a specific dev tool version bug, I believe that some info that will help future user to see if they are using the same versions could help.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. It seems like `xxxx.ascx.g.cs` file was deleted. I just renamed the webpart like `originalname` to `originalname2` then `ascx.g.cs` file was created by itself again and problem was gone. Then I renamed file name back to  the original name.